# Cannot obtain a DataReader from the specified data flow when DelayValidation is set to False

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SSIS 2012 with SSDT and VS 2012.

I'm getting the error : "Could not obtain a DataReader object from the specified data flow component." when trying to `dtsCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default)` on every package I create. I am sure that the property DelayValidation is set to False on flow task and its parent and ValidateExternalMetadata is set to True on DataReader.

When the package is executed using the `dtsCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`, it returns 0 after 30 secs (the default timeout), so it seems that everything is fine with it.

The C# code is coming from BOL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135917.aspx

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detail was missing from my question, I was running the C# code inside an unit test with R#.
It seems that there is a problem with it. I tried to execute the code from a console application and everything went fine at the first time.